# How can I add a check box in Google Sheets based on the content of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of four options in a cell. Three of them require "approval" so I need a checkbox in the cell beside it. For one option, I do not want the checkbox to appear. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

it can be tricked with conditional formatting where custom formula will be something like:

```
=COUNTIF(A1,"Option 4")
```

and font color will be set to custom color:

```
#fffffd
```

Answer (score 0):

Entire range of cells in the column, right click on the selected column and choose "Data Validation" and then choose "Checkbox" for the criteria. Then all your "TRUE" and "FALSE" cells will be checked or unchecked checkboxes.